# Random Sampling with Distance Condition

Tags: r, random

I want to sample two integers x and y at random from an interval [1,N] such that |x-y| >= D, for some D < N. The code below (written in R) is what I have been using but it is terribly inefficient. Are there better methods for this sort of sampling? Thanks in adv.

```
N <- 100; D <- 10;

i <- sample(1:N, 2)

while ( abs( i[1] - i[2] ) < D ){
   i <- sort(sample(1:N, 2))
}
```

Comment: doesnt seem inefficient at all--why do you say that? for a distance of 10 and values 1 to 100, the majority of times you will only need to call `sample` once

Comment: I guess (in)efficiency depends on the specific use case, but most importantly this algorithm is not constant time since `P(|x-y| >= D)` for any call to sample(1:N, 2) is something along the line of `1 - [(N-x)/N + (x-0)/N + 2D/N]`, with P(x) = 1/N, for any x,y in [1:N] and D < N. That is, for any small or large x, and sufficiently large N & D, the probability to run ´sample()´ more than once is growing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the key is to realize that y is dependent on x (or the other way around). Here's the algorithm that should work in at most three steps:

```
1. sample x from [1:N]
2. sample y from [1:(x-D)] if (x-D) >= 1
   sample y from [x + D:N] if (x+D) <= N
3. If both conditions for y are met, choose one of the generated y  uniform at random
```

The idea is that once x was sampled, y needs to be in the range [1:(x-D)] or [x+D:N] in order to satisfy |x-y| >= D.

Examples:

N=100; D=10

```
a) x is close to N

1. x is sampled from 1:N as 95
2. to satisfy |x-y| >= D, y can be at most 85, so the range to sample y is [1:85]

b) x is close to 1

1. x is sampled from 1:N as 9
2. y must be at least 19, so the range to sample y is [19:N]

c) x is close to 50

1. x is sampled from 1:N as 45
2. y must be either at most 35, or at least 55, so the ranges to sample from are [1:35] and [55:N]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by first randomly sampling a difference between the numbers is greater than or equal to `D`.  In other words, we want to sample numbers between `D` and `N-1` with replacement.

```
difference <- sample(D:(N-1), 20, replace = TRUE)
```

Now all we need to do is select our lower number by selecting a number between `1` and `N - difference`.  We can do this using `vapply`.

```
lowerval <- vapply(N - difference, sample, numeric(1), 1)
```

Finally we get the upper value by adding the difference to the lower value.

```
upperval <- lowerval + difference
```

Comment: One thing to note is that the distribution using this algorithm will be different than the distribution using OP's algorithm. So depending on any other requirements that are needed from the random sampling this may or may not be what they want.